# Unable to pass private registry credentials to Azure Iot Edge

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-edge

I am using kubernetes with virtual-kubelet to deploy module to Iot Edge.
Everything works perfect with public image. 
I can't figure out how to pass credentials to my private registry.

This documentation https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/iot-edge/iot-edge-runtime.md says:

> settings.image – The container image that the IoT Edge agent uses to
>   start the module. The IoT Edge agent must be configured with
>   credentials for the container registry if the image is protected by a
>   password. Credentials for the container registry can be configured
>   remotely using the deployment manifest, **or on the IoT Edge device
>   itself by updating the config.yaml** file in the IoT Edge program
>   folder.

Seems very easy but can't find how to modify config.yaml to add my credentials.
I think that it should be added in below section but there is no example how to do that.

```
###############################################################################
# Edge Agent module spec
###############################################################################
#
# Configures the initial Edge Agent module.
#
# The daemon uses this definition to bootstrap the system. The Edge Agent can
# then update itself based on the Edge Agent module definition present in the
# deployment in IoT Hub.
#
###############################################################################

agent:
  name: "edgeAgent"
  type: "docker"
  env:
    RuntimeLogLevel: debug
  config:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.0"
    auth: {}
```

YAML

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: matrix
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: matrix
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 0%
      maxUnavailable: 100%
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: matrix
      annotations:
        isEdgeDeployment: "true"
        targetCondition: "tags.type='gpu'"
        priority: "151"
        loggingOptions: ""
    spec:
      affinity:
          podAntiAffinity:
            requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                - key: app
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - matrix
              topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      containers:
      - name: matrix
        image: "registry.xxx.xx/image/xxx-frontend"
        env:
        - name: DISPLAY
          value: ":0.0"
      nodeSelector:
        type: virtual-kubelet
      tolerations:
      - key: virtual-kubelet.io/provider
        operator: Equal
        value: iotedge
        effect: NoSchedule

---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: matrix
data:
  status: running
  restartPolicy: always
  version: "1.0"
  createOptions: |
    {
      "HostConfig": {
        "Privileged": "true",
        "Mounts": [{"Target": "/tmp/.X11-unix/","Source": "/tmp/.X11-unix/","Type": "bind"}],
        "network": "host"
      }
    }
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: edgeagent
data:
  desiredProperties: |
    {
      "runtime": {
        "settings": {
          "registryCredentials": {
            "docker": {
              "address": "registry.xxx.xx",
              "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
              "username": "user"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "systemModules": {
        "edgeHub": {
          "env": {
            "OptimizeForPerformance": {
              "value": "false"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: edgehub
data:
  desiredProperties: |
    {
      "routes": {
        "route": "FROM /* INTO $upstream",
      },
      "storeAndForwardConfiguration": {
        "timeToLiveSecs": 6
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to `edgeAgent` configMap like so:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: edgeagent
data:
  desiredProperties: |
    {
      "runtime": {
        "settings": {
          "registryCredentials": {
            "docker": {
              "address": "preview.azurecr.io",
              "password": "xyz",
              "username": "abc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
---
```

Comment: Hello. I've edited my question and added my yaml. Still see "denied: access forbidden" in edgeAgent logs.

Comment: Image names need to have tag, for example:
"registry.xxx.xx/image/xxx-frontend:latest" or "registry.xxx.xx/image/xxx-frontend:1.0"

Comment: Also, if you want to put the container on the host network, please use these create options:
`{
 "NetworkingConfig": {
  "EndpointsConfig": {
   "host": {}
  }
 },
 "HostConfig": {
  "NetworkMode": "host"
 }
}`